# Error while sending QUERY packet

Tags: cache

I have a includeJS variable set that populates a javascript calendar from an entries loop, with a large amount of entries which needs to be cached.

Whenever I cache this section I get this error:

`Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=11878`

What's the problem here?

Comment: `cache` is useless if the thing you're caching doesn't directly output HTML. Instead of using `includeJs`, perhaps it makes sense to output a `<script>` tag, and cache that.

Comment: When I use the script tag I still get the same QUERY packet error

Comment: I've narrowed this down now.... seems there is a limit to the size of a cached object.

If I try to cache a loop of 200 entries then it gives me the php warning.

Is it possible to up this limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So turns out this is to do with the size of the packet being sent to the database cache.

My server had a limit of: 
max_allowed_packet = 1M

Doubling this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error. Changing the allow_max_packet did not work. Turns out it was my general.db file. I have it set up for a multi-environment config. This is what fixed it:

Changing

```
    '*' => array(
         'defaultImageQuality' => 80,
    ),
```

to this:

```
    'defaultImageQuality' => 80,
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense? Do you know why the multi-environment config caused it? Have you talked to P&T about it?